# How can I detect SNAT port exhaustion on Azure using Datadog metrics?

Tags: azure, nat, datadog, azure-vm-scale-set, azure-load-balancer

Here's a [list](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/azure_load_balancer/) of DataDog metrics of Azure Load Balancer that are available to use. It seems like

```
azure.network_loadbalancers.allocated_snat_ports (count) - Total number of SNAT ports allocated within time period,
azure.network_loadbalancers.snat_connection_count (count) - Total number of new SNAT connections created within time period,
azure.network_loadbalancers.used_snat_ports (count) - Total number of SNAT ports used within time period
```

are the most releveant.

> When SNAT port resources are exhausted, outbound flows fail. You could observe failing outbound connections or are advised by support that you're exhausting SNAT ports.

> Simply seeing failed connections does not confirm SNAT exhaustion. Seeing the failed connections was a clue we were having an issue but there is no way to confirm SNAT exhaustion w/o a ticket to Microsoft it turns out.

Answer (score 0):

There is a preview feature that allows you to graph your SNAT port usage and allocation, see:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-standard-diagnostics#how-do-i-check-my-snat-port-usage-and-allocation

Comment: That's great, but I'd like to set up an alert system using Datadog.